# Is there any way to see the functions that are executed after pushing a link or a button in a web page done with PHP?

Tags: php

is there any way to see the functions that are called after pushing a link or a button in a web page done with PHP?

I user Firefox.

Regards

Javi

Comment: Please choose answers for your questions. 9% is way too low.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve but you could install/configure a [debugger module](http://de.php.net/debugger) like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).
Then you can either step through the code or use the [profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to see which functions have been hit (and how long they took).

Answer (score 1):

It it's your own code, open it in the editor.
If it's someone's else code, there is no way.